# nodejs for background process, not a http server

Tags: node.js

Im new to nodejs, i am looking for a way to create a nodejs process that can run in the background. All the example I can find is to create a node http server. I don't need to listen for any web request i just need to startup a process and have it listen to a message queue.

Comment: How do messages get in the message queue?  Is it listening to a socket?  You must be listening to some kind of outside agent, right?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: @Eatdoku did you figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS has enough API to be used for versatile tasks, not just HTTP Servers. You have two problems to solve:

1. Run Node process continuously. So, you'd need some equivalent of `http.listen()` so the process just don't exit. Whatever you intent to do, you'd probably need Node waiting for some external events.
2. Run node as a `daemon` or `service`. There are plenty of modules to help, `foreman`, `pm2`. You can make this process auto-start by using `upstart` on linux machines and [`node-window`](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) for windows.